# I'm as a user, what should I input to cause a non value-error or zerodivision-error in this code? #python

Tags: python, exception, error-handling

[First, I'm sorry for my bad english]
I'm as user not programmer in here, I'm challenged by my teacher to input something in this program to make a non value error or zerodivision error so that the program show the last except `"mysterious error happened, sorry"`. What should I input?

```
import math
def main():
    print('A program to find the root of the quadratic equation')
    try:
        a = float(input('a = '))
        b = float(input('b= '))
        c = float(input('c = '))
        discriminant = b * b - 4 * a * c
        squareDisc = math.sqrt(discriminant)
        root1 = (-b + squareDisc) / (2 * a)
        root2 = (-b - squareDisc) / (2 * a)
        print(' x1 =', root1)
        print(' x2 =', root2)
    except ValueError as obyekExcept:
        if str(obyekExcept) == 'math domain error':
            print('\nDont have real root')
        else:
            print('\nYou give non number input')
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print('\nYou are providing an input which results in zero division')
    except:
        print("\nmysterious error happen, sorry")
main()
```

Comment: If your question is answered, please mark the answer as correct. :)

Comment: @SidharthRamesh I'm sorry, but how to do it? Or i have done it now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just try hitting `ctrl + c` when prompted for input.
This would normally make the program exit, but since you're catching all exceptions, it will print `mysterious error happen, sorry`.

Answer (score 1):

When I ran it in the terminal, I managed to crash it by pressing `Control+C`:

```
A program to find the root of the quadratic equation
a = ^C
mysterious error happen, sorry
```

Answer (score 0):

If you input `0` for `a`, you will get `ZeroDivisionError`.

```
A program to find the root of the quadratic equation

a = 0

b= 3

c = 2


You are providing an input which results in zero division
```

If you try to input some numbers that will cause `ValueError` you will get the first exception. (you need to calculate first)

```
A program to find the root of the quadratic equation

a = 7

b= 4

c = 2

Dont have real root
```

For the last error message, there are already answers.